# BeautifulSoup, ignore <a> </a> tags and get al the text inside <p> </p>

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the text inside every `<p>` tag which belongs to `news1`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r1  = requests.get("http://www.metalinjection.net/shocking-revelations/machine-heads-robb-flynn-addresses-controversial-photo-from-his-past-in-the-wake-of-charlottesville")
data1 = r1.text
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "lxml")
news1 = soup1.find_all("div", {"class": "article-detail"})

for x in news1:
    print x.find("p").text
```

this get the first `<p>` text and only that..when called find_all it gives following error

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

so I made a list.but still getting the same error??

```
text1 = []
for x in news1:
    text1.append(x.find_all("p").text)

print text1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error i get when running your code is: `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'`, which is reasonable as a bs4 `ResultSet` is basically a list of `Tag` elements. You can get the text of every 'p' tag if you loop over that iterable.

```
text1 = []
for x in news1:
    for i in x.find_all("p"):
        text1.append(i.text)
```

Or as a one-liner, using list comprehensions:

```
text1 = [i.text for x in news1 for i in x.find_all("p")]
```

Comment: well... I am having another problem. I keep getting \n2019, \n203 ......like parts within texts..I use replace("\n2019  ", " ' ") to fix them.sometimes that doesn't work......any solution?

Comment: You mean `'\u2019'`, etc? Those are unicode characters. You can replace them with: `i.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`